# Framework for iPhone / iOS asynchronous multiplayer gaming?

Tags: iphone, asynchronous, ios

I'm curious if anyone knows of any frameworks that enable *asynchronous* multiplayer gaming in iOS?

I know GameKit/Game Center eases *synchronous* (realtime) multiplayer gaming - I'm thinking of something more like Words With Friends. There would obviously need to be a server-side element that I'd have to provide, to store game state and send "your turn" notifications - just wondering if anyone's already invented some of this wheel or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I interpret your question correctly. OpenFeint is not suitable to your needs, I suppose?

If not, you might consider checking out www.smartfoxserver.com (a multiplayer server, very scalable, allows you to program server-side extensions in a number of languages).

Comment: I wasn't actually aware that OpenFeint did so :). I suppose that would be my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into SmartFoxPro if openfeint is not for you. It can store games in MySql for you, and send notifications and such.